# .net core web API endpoints returning 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, .net-core-2.2

I implemented Jwt for authorization in my asp.net core application but I'm getting 401 error for all endpoints I decorate with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AccessKey")]`even though I'm passing the correct access key with the request headers.

Here is is my Jwt implementation

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     ValidateActor = true,
                     ValidateAudience = true,
                     ValidateLifetime = true,
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                     ValidIssuer = appSettings.SecurityConfiguration.TokenIssuer,
                     ValidAudience = appSettings.SecurityConfiguration.AppName,
                     IssuerSigningKey =
                         new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                             Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSettings.SecurityConfiguration.IssuerSigningKey))
                 };
                 options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                 {
                     OnMessageReceived = context =>
                     {
                         if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/hubs/notification") &&
                             context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("access_token", out StringValues token)
                         )
                         {
                             context.Token = token;
                         }

                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                     },
                     OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                     {
                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                     }
                 };

                 options.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx =>
                     ctx.Request.IsAccessKeyRequest(appSettings) ? AccessKeyAuthOptions.DefaultScheme : null;

             }).AddAccessKeyAuthentication(options =>
             {

             });
```

The `AddAccessKeyAuthentication` extension method is implemented below

```
public static void AddAccessKeyAuthentication(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AccessKeyAuthOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        builder.AddScheme<AccessKeyAuthOptions, AccessKeyAuthenticationHandler>(AccessKeyAuthOptions.DefaultScheme, configureOptions);
    }
```

I read through some past solved questions and most suggest adding `app.UseAuthorization()` in the configure method of Startup class but I'm getting `IApplicationBuilder doesn't contain definition for UseAuthorization and no extension method..` error, I'm using .net core 2.2 and I can't find it here. Upgrading to 3.x isn't an option for me because I have a lot of things depending on 2.2. Someone should help figure out what's wrong please

Comment: I think that `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AccessKey")]` is wrong. Since you are not defining your JWT to "AccessKey" you will want to change that to `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` otherwise you would need to define that name like so `services.AddAuthentication("AccessKey")`

Comment: @A.Hasemeyer I added AccessKey authorization in the extension method already. However, I changed it to what you suggested but it's still returning 401

Comment: I would verify that you are using the correct libraries. According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.1 the `app.UseAuthentication()` syntax has been in place since at least .Net Core 2.0. And I use it in 3.1 so it should work in 2.2